# Emulator launchs activity that is not declared as starting

Tags: android-activity, android-manifest

Here is my manifest snippet:

```
<activity android:name=".EntranceView" >
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity >
<activity android:name=".MainView">
</activity>
```

The problem is that on application start the .MainView activity launchs, not .EntranceView that is declared as starting activity.

Comment: Try cleaning your project. This manifest looks just fine. You probably have some old junk lying around that is being used instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed .MainView to .GeneralView. Weird, but it works for me.